# Windows forms + windows service

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-service

Tenho um projeto windows forms, adicionei uma classe windows service, gostaria de instalar o serviço e executar a partir de um evento de um botão(sem a necessidade de utilizar o Installutil).

Tem alguma maneira de fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ferramenta `Installutil.exe` é um utilitário de linha de comando que permite instalar e desinstalar servidores de recursos executando os componentes de instalação em assemblies especificados.

`Installutil.exe` usa [reflexão](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getexportedtypes?view=netframework-4.8) para inspecionar os assemblies especificados e encontrar todos os tipos de instaladores [`Installer`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.configuration.install.installer?view=netframework-4.8) que têm o atributo [`System.ComponentModel.RunInstallerAttribute`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.runinstallerattribute?view=netframework-4.8) definido como `true`.

Em seguida, a ferramenta executa o método [`Installer.Install`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.configuration.install.installer.install?view=netframework-4.8) ou [`Installer.Uninstall`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.configuration.install.installer.uninstall?view=netframework-4.8) em cada instância do tipo de `Installer` encontrada.